# flask-admin ModelView custom create_form

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, flask-admin

I am creating a custom `UserViewCreateForm` (using wtforms) in my flask-admin as follows:-

```
from app.vendors.models import Vendor

class UserViewCreateForm(form.Form):
    username = fields.TextField('Username')
    first_name = fields.TextField('First Name')
    last_name = fields.TextField('Last Name')
    email = fields.TextField('Email')
    contact_number = fields.TextField('Contact Number')
    password = fields.PasswordField('Password')
    is_admin = fields.BooleanField('Is Admin')
    is_active = fields.BooleanField('Is Active')
    is_verified = fields.BooleanField('Is Verified')
    vendor = fields.SelectField('Vendor', coerce=int)


class UserView(ModelView):
    form_overrides = dict(title=SelectField)
    form_args = dict(
        # Pass the choices to the `SelectField`
        title=dict(
            choices=TITLE_TYPE
        ))

    def __init__(self, session, **kwargs):
        super(UserView, self).__init__(User, session, **kwargs)

    def is_accessible(self):
        return login.current_user.is_authenticated()

    def create_form(self):
        form = UserViewCreateForm()
        form.vendor.choices = [(0, '')] + [(v.id, v.name) for v in Vendor.query.all()]
        return form
```

The vendor select field is giving me a `Not a valid choice` validation error.

What am I doing wrongly?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly because you have no choices?

```
CA_STATES = [
    ('', 'Province'),
    ('AB', 'Alberta'),
    ('BC', 'British Columbia'),
    ('MB', 'Manitoba'),
    ('NB', 'New Brunswick'),
    ('NL', 'Newfoundland and Labrador'),
    ('NS', 'Nova Scotia'),
    ('ON', 'Ontario'),
    ('PE', 'Prince Edward Island'),
    ('QC', 'Quebec'),
    ('SK', 'Saskatchewan'),
    ('NT', 'Northwest Territories'),
    ('NU', 'Nunavut'),
    ('YT', 'Yukon'),
]

state_ca = SelectField('Province', choices=CA_STATES)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pull your choices from your vendor table, then you want a QuerySelectField from wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy (prior to WTForms 3.0 - after 3.0, it's now a seperate WTForms-SQLAlchemy package.)

```
from app.vendors.models import Vendor
from wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy import QuerySelectField

class UserViewCreateForm(form.Form):
    username = fields.TextField('Username')
    first_name = fields.TextField('First Name')
    last_name = fields.TextField('Last Name')
    email = fields.TextField('Email')
    contact_number = fields.TextField('Contact Number')
    password = fields.PasswordField('Password')
    is_admin = fields.BooleanField('Is Admin')
    is_active = fields.BooleanField('Is Active')
    is_verified = fields.BooleanField('Is Verified')
    vendor = QuerySelectField('Vendor')

class UserView(ModelView):

    def create_form(self):
        form = UserViewCreateForm()
        form.vendor.query = Vendor.query.all()
        return form
```